# Is Sencha Touch a UI framework that can (or should?) be used with PhoneGap?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm planning to develop my first mobile app and wanted to leverage my skills as a web developer. Thus, I started to look at PhoneGap. In the process, I realized that I probably should use some sort of UI framework. It seems that jQuery Mobile has speed issues. Sencha Touch 2 supposedly is faster. So, I figured I should use PhoneGap + Sencha Touch 2.

However, it's seems to be that Sencha Touch 2 is not a UI framework. It seems to be something similar to PhoneGap. I might be heading in the wrong direction here.

Questions:

1. Is it a good idea to combine PhoneGap and Sencha Touch 2?
2. Are there other UI frameworks worth looking at?

Comment: What all exactly are you looking to do? Because I've been using Cordova + JQuery Mobile on a project at work. The only real "speed issues" I've noticed are between certain page transitions, other than that it's been awesome. And JQuery Mobile is widely used with a strong community. If you're looking for something more lightweight you could look into [jQT](http://jqtjs.com/), which uses Zepto.

Comment: I've never used jQM, but I don't want to run into UI issues like slow page transition. Based on my research, it seems that Sencha is better suited for mobile apps.

Comment: It definitely just depends on what you want to do. jQM is much easier to learn and get started with, but Sencha might give you a more of a native feel. jQM has definitely improved a lot though, and keeps improving. I'd say try them both, worst thing that could happen is you figure out which one you like best and you don't use the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Sencha Touch is totally different from PhoneGap.

PhoneGap in a nutshell gives you javascript APIs which access native apis on many mobile platform.

**Sencha Touch 2 is essentially a cross-platform mobile web framework.** Although several native apis are introduced in Sencha Touch 2, please note that it's not the most important thing which makes ST2 outstanding. ST2 is best known for its solid and flexible class system, rapid mobile-web application development (then probably packaged as a native app), and **robust UI customization** as it utilizes SASS well.

It seems you are new to ST2, so please read the following articles carefully:

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/getting_started

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/first_app

And especially you have to understand this article thoroughly if you want to get the most important concepts of the class system.

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/class_system