# Cross-platform web frameworks - the difference

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have a problem with understanding which of those frameworks is designed for what purpose.
Here:

http://codegeekz.com/mobile-frameworks-for-developers/

20 frameworks are listed. What I do understand is that they help to create android/ios applications with html, css and JS.

But what I don't undertand is the difference. What is PhoneGap and Appcelerator then and what is Sencha-touch, jQueryMobile, Fries, etc.

I see here:
[Is Sencha Touch a UI framework that can (or should?) be used with PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137594/is-sencha-touch-a-ui-framework-that-can-or-should-be-used-with-phonegap) that Sencha Touch 2 is a cross-platform web framework, so can I use it with jQueryMobile for example or how does it all works? How I can combine those frameworks because honestly - I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: check this http://www.gajotres.net/sencha-touch-vs-jquery-mobile/

Comment: ok, so jqueryMobile and Sencha Touch are.. let's call it - on the same level, yes?

Comment: jQM and Sencha touch can be integrated with phonegap/cordova. But i'm not sure whether jQM and Sencha can work together.

Comment: and what part of this is Appcelerator? what I can create in it and which frameworks I can use with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Intro

I will write you which frameworks are made for hybrid mobile app creation.

### List

This is the list of currently top 5 used frameworks:

- jQuery Mobile - Free

  Probably mostly used framework
  Easy like hell
  Slowest of them all
  Large online community
- Sencha Touch - Free/Commercial

  Second mostly used framework
  Hard to learn and master, specially if you are not good with vanilla javascript
  Fast
  Large online community
- AppFramework - Free

  Easy to master
  Fast
  Bad community support, at least compared to other listed frameworks
- Kendo UI - Free/Commercial

  Easy to master, very similar to jQuery Mobile
  Fast
  Good/Great online support
  Unfortunately you will need to buy a license in case of commercial product
- PhoneJS - Free/Commercial

  Easy to master, very similar to jQuery Mobile
  Fast
  Average online support
  Great documentation
  Unfortunately you will need to buy a license in case of commercial product
- Appcelerator - Free/Commercial

  Not that easy to master, yet simpler then Sencha Touch
  Fastest of them all - Native app
  Good online support
  Unfortunately you will need to buy a license in case of commercial product
  Least customizable among listed frameworks

### Question answers

This is only one part of the story. You will also need a native packaging framework and this is where Phonegap comes. It is used as a place holder for mobile javascript HTML5 frameworks. Basically it wraps HTML/JS/CSS into a native application and gives them ability to access smartphone features like camera.

Appcelerator is something different, it uses javascript to generate native application. But unlike Phonegap, Appcelerator is fully native app, javascript is only used to construct app during the development process.

Mobile HTML5 frameworks should not be used together, for example there's no point in combining Sencha Touch and jQuery Mobile. Bot of them are fully designed frameworks, not to mention built on completely different premise. Sencha Touch is fully javascript based framework, where everything is done through javascript alone. jQuery Mobile framework is more HTML5 oriented and jQuery is used in the background. Same goes for Kendo UI and PhoneJS.

Comment: Thank You very much. So I understand that I can create apps in JS in Appcelerator? And then it creates a native app? And also - I can't use html and css while creating in Appcelerator?

Comment: Appcelerator will create full native app and you can't use HTML or CSS to style it. You can style it as much as platform supports it.

Comment: Thanks again. Also - how I can develope in PhoneJS/Kendo UI ? Do I need PhoneGap or it can be done in Appcelerator? And what is Sencha? I know Sencha Touch is framework which I can combine with PhoneGap, but I think it is also something..more xD can You explain?